# RDP service not displayed under services for remote computer

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a jumpstation which i connect to remotely, from here on i launch services.msc and choose connect to another computer to display the set of services running on server X. I can see majority of services running however i am not able to see RDP service listed ( RDP is disabled and needs to be enabled via the jumpstation so that i could remote on to server X from the jumpstation). Is there any reason you can think of why RDP service is not listed under services.msc?

Regards,

Comment: Is it still so that Windows differentiates between "services" and "features"? I believe RDP is/was considered a feature, and not a service.

Comment: Hi @Tom but RDP is listed under services right? Which makes it a mix of Service/feature? And it shall be able to be started remotely?

Comment: The service name is `TermService` and it muste be started an configured correctly to allow connections. Configuration can be done via `RemoteRegistry`service. The key for allowing connections is `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server` (change `fDenyTSConnection` to `0`).

Comment: hi @bjoster i believe the service that you are referring to is different. I also believe that the purpose of that registry is different to what I have asked for. Thank you for the help though :)

Comment: What is the name of the specific service you are interested in?

Comment: hi, I am interested in being able to enable Remote Desktop Service (Service) from a jumpstation server.

Comment: The service name for RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) is "TermService".

Comment: Hi @bjoster I am not able to see that listed under services too. if you can send me your email address, i can send you some screenshots maybe? So you can possibly have a better understanding? Thanks

Comment: Only if I cann bill you :-) You can search for services: `sc <SERVER X> query | find /i "term"`